# Android Null Pointer Exception on drawColor

Tags: java, android, canvas, nullpointerexception

I have some problem, here in my code I am trying to draw canvas on frameLayout but I am getting Null Object Reference exception. By the way when I changed Color.BLACK nothing change only show black rectangle and give error.
I use android studio 2.1 and genymotion android emulator 6.0 Marshmallow

**Error** is like that :

```
Fatal Exception:main
Process:com.example.myApp
java.lang.NullPointerException : Attempt to invoke virtual method "void android.graphics.Canvas.rawColor(int)" on a null object reference
```

---

```
public class MyCanvas extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private boolean mRun= false;
    private final SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private final Object mRunLock = new Object();

    public MyCanvas(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){

        super(context,attrs);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.AddCallback(this);   
    }

    public synchronized void run(){

        if(mRun){

            Canvas c = null;
            try{

                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder){
                    synchronized(mRunLock){
                        if(mRun) doDraw(c);
                    }

                }

            }finally
                if(c != null)
                { mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasandPost(c);    }

        }   


    }


    private void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
       canvas.drawColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }
}
```

my activity layout code is here.

```
<view class="com.example.myapp.MyCanvas"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:lid="@+id/mycanvas"
/>
```

my activity class is here

```
MyCanvas myCanvas = (MyCanvas)findViewById(R.id.mycanvas);
myCanvas.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the canvas returned from [lockCanvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas()) is null.

Quoting the docs:

> The returned Canvas can be used to draw into the surface's bitmap. A
>   null is returned if the surface has not been created or otherwise
>   cannot be edited. You will usually need to implement
>   Callback.surfaceCreated to find out when the Surface is available for
>   use.

So you must implement [Callback.surfaceCreated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.Callback.html#surfaceCreated(android.view.SurfaceHolder)) and start editing your canvas after surfaceCreated is being invoked.

Comment: Thanks surfacedestroyed method worked.  When i assign mRun to false in destroyed, error gone.